# Starting the code at the point which Python has been crashed

Tags: python, crash, save, savestate

I am new user of Python. I have a project which its running to get answer will last for many hours and maybe days while it is calculating and saving myriad of outputs in a `txt` or `csv` file.

Let us assume that while working, laptop run out of charge, or system is crashed and etc. so the whole work will be destroyed.
I know there is some way to tell Python to save data on that point and after running the code again, it starts from that point not from the beginning.

Could any one help me please?
It is of utmost importance.

I appreciate your help and your attention.

Comment: If the computer shuts down unexpectedly, there is no way to tell Python to react to that. What you could try is modify your code so that the output is stored after certain time intervals (say every hour a new csv is created with all the output from the last hour). At least this way you will not lose all your data.

Comment: @tank1610 thank you friend. there is a way for crashing, running out of charge, hanging the windows and... it is performed already in COSMOMC in Fortrn.